# What are the meanings of the participial phrase and the verb-less clause?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> From you have I been absent in the spring,
>  When proud-pied April
>   dress'd in all his trim
>  Hath put a spirit of youth in every
>   thing
>  That heavy Saturn laugh'd and leap'd with him.
>  Yet nor
>   the lays of birds nor the sweet smell
>  Of different flowers in
>   odor and in hue
>  Could make me any summer's story tell.
>  Or
>   from their proud lap pluck them while they grew;
>  Nor did I wonder
>   at the lily's white,
>  Nor praise the deep vermilion in the
>   rose;
>  They were but sweet, but figures of delight; **[C]**
>   Drawn after you **[A]**, you pattern of all those.**[B]**
>  Yet
>   seem'd it winter still, and, you away,
>  As with your shadow I with
>   these did play.
>  (Virginia Woolf, To the Lighthouse, p.132; Sonnet
>   98, [William Shakespeare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_98))

I guess participial phrase [A] is selected to say the condition of previous clause [C], and comma and verb-less clause [B] is to say the reason of [C]. Is this right?

Comment: Interpreting song lyrics or poetry should not be on-topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno OP does not ask for interpretation, she asks for grammatical analysis - very different thing.

Comment: I still think it's an grammatical interpretation of the text. Does doing grammar analysis of Shakespeare basing on modern grammar make sense? Let's do it for _Beowulf_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You're illegitimately confounding literary interpretation of the whole, which is off-topic, with grammatical analysis of a part of a single sentence, which is on-topic. The fact that the sentence is drawn from a 17th-century sonnet is wholly irrelevant;  except for the play on 'but' (which OP does ask about) there is nothing in the lexicon or the syntax which is not entirely modern. And your reference to *Beowulf* is also irrelevant; this is Early Modern English, not Old English.

Comment: I know that _Beowulf_ is written in Old English, but Early Modern English is not Modern English. I am not sure what the OP would get from asking about Early Modern English, when s/he studied Modern English grammar. I don't think I questions about Early Modern English are on-topic here: There is already EL&U for that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno This **is** ModE syntax. "They are only examples, extracted from the data, the data itself provides the rules." If I take away the context (we **always** demand context) you can't tell it's EME. Or that it's poetry, either, though you've abandoned that spurious line of argument. Shall I edit to remove the context? Will that make it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just by way of warning: the semicolon is editorial; in the only source text, this is a colon. Elizabethan pointing was (to the extent that it was anything consistent) rhetorical, not mechanical, and in any case there's no knowing what Shakespeare originally wrote; so you can't depend on the point to mean anything in particular.

[A] and [B] are both reduced clauses, with omitted verbs. That verb is "were" from C, the entire preceding line.

[A] also omits its subject, and when you first hear the clause, you naturally parse it as an ordinary reduced relative clause, "They were ... but figures ... [which were] drawn after you".

[B], however, is an independent clause with a new subject: "You [were] the pattern of all those"; and when you hear this clause and recognize the antithesis it expresses, you  realize that [A] is ambiguous. In light of what **precedes** it, [A] is a relative clause with the relative pronoun *which* as its omitted subject; but in light of what **follows** it, [A] may also be understood as an independent clause with the personal pronoun *they* as its subject.

So you've got a double parsing, which may be paraphrased either as:

> They were only sweet images of delight, [which were] drawn with you as the model; you [were] the authentic original.
>   They were only sweet images of delight: they [were] drawn with you as the model, you [were] the authentic original.